# What do you call a person(employee) who follows instructions?

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary, american-english, british-english

If you have a junior who has a positive quality of following instructions/orders, what would be the formal word for it?

Comment: Obedient. Compliant.

Comment: You would have cause for complaint if they didn't follow instructions! If you mean they are especially careful about following the instructions accurately, you can say they are _diligent_ or _painstaking_.